# Number of words that can be formed from the letters of the word ENGINEER so that order of the vowels do not change?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Number of words that can be formed from the letters of the word ENGINEER so that order of the vowels do not change?

My work : Since order of vowels does not change, the order should always be EIEE. So I assumed it to be a single object ( EIEE) and arranged it along with NGNR in $5!/2!$ ways. But in this case, the situation when first E is separated by rest IEE and many more like that are not included. So how do I involve all cases?

Comment: So, you have to fill in the blanks given $_E_I_E_E_$.  That's five blanks and you have four letters to use.  So, first you need to count the five tuples of non-negative integers that sum to four.  Now you have to permute $NGNR$ and divide accordingly.

Comment: That will lead to 5C4 . 4!/2=60. Am I right?

Comment: There are more than $\binom 54$ five-tuples.  That's only $5$. There are already five ways to do it if you put all the letters in one slot.

Comment: I will be glad if you put some of the cases in the answer

Comment: In this case the numbers are so small that you can do it all out.  In general, with larger numbers,  a technique like [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) is useful.

Comment: I think Ribet's [Stars and Bars](https://youtu.be/UTCScjoPymA) explanation on numberphile is top of the line.

Comment: Got it. But I thought that can only be used when say all objects are identical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are five positions to be filled with the letters $N,G,N,R$:
$$ \text{_ E _ I _ E _ E _} $$
Step 1: Let $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ be the number of letters in the relevant positions. Then:
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=4, \\
0\le x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\le 4$$
Using stars and bars it is:
$${4+5-1\choose 5-1}={8\choose 4}.$$
Step 2: Permutation of the four letters $N,G,N,R$ is:
$$\frac{4!}{2!}.$$
Hence, the total number of words is:
$${8\choose 4}\cdot \frac{4!}{2!}=840.$$

Answer (score 2):

You should simply count the number of arrangements of the letters N-G-N-R among eight positions, i.e. $(8!/(4!4!))*(4!/2!)$.

Comment: The method described by @lulu does work.  First, you choose how many of the four letters go in each  of the five spaces, then you arrange them in those spaces.  Done properly, you obtain $\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{2}2!$, which is equal to the answer you obtained.

Comment: Thanks for your remark. I'm afraid I read the comment too fast.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two additional methods:

**Method 1:** We use symmetry.

The word $ENGINEER$ has eight letters, of which three are $E$s, two are $N$s, one is a $G$, one is an $I$, and one is an $R$.  We can choose three of the positions for the $E$s, two of the remaining five positions for the $N$s, and arrange the remaining three distinct letters in the three remaining spaces in 
$$\binom{8}{3}\binom{5}{2}3!$$
ways.

By symmetry, one fourth of these arrangements will have an $I$ in the second position among the four vowels.  Hence, the number of admissible arrangements is 
$$\frac{1}{4}\binom{8}{3}\binom{5}{2}3!$$

**Method 2:**  We place the consonants, then the vowels.

We choose two of the eight positions for the two $N$s, one of the remaining six positions for the $G$, and one of the remaining five positions for the $R$.  There is only one way to arrange the vowels in the remaining four positions so that they appear in the same order that they do in the word $ENGINEER$.  Hence, the number of admissible arrangements is 
$$\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{1}$$