# Find The Number of ways in which letters of the word ENGINEER can be arranged so that no two alike letters are together

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

My attempt was based on principles of exclusion-inclusion but I'm unsure how to exclude in this case as the arrangements in which 'EEE' occur together are a complete subset of the arrangements in which 'EE' occur together. Could someone recommend a better method/ Elaborate how inclusion-exclusion works in such cases? The answer is supposed to be 960.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2905052/number-of-words-that-can-be-formed-from-the-letters-of-the-word-engineer-so-that

Comment: In the link I shared, it is digits instead of letters otherwise it is exactly the same question.

Comment: Thanks a ton both of you! That answers my question perfectly :)